# Переключение между Табами (вкладками) HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Имеются вкладки для переключения контента. Вкладки обёрнуты ссылками.
Через JS происходит переключение вкладок.

Проблема в том, что при клике на пустое место во вкладки - переключение срабатывает, а при клике например на тексте внутри вкладки - не срабатывает.

Как реализовать так, чтобы переключение происходило и по клику вложенных элементов?

Пример реализации вкладок:

```
<a href="#tab1" class="tabs__link tabs__link_active">
              <div class="tabs__link-top">
              </div>
              <div class="tabs__link-desc">
                Content
              </div>
              <div class="tabs__link-price">
                Content
              </div>
            </a>
<a href="#tab2" class="tabs__link">
              <div class="tabs__link-top">
              </div>
              <div class="tabs__link-desc">
                Content
              </div>
              <div class="tabs__link-price">
                Content
              </div>
            </a>
```

JS:

```
var $tabs = function (target) {
      var
        _elemTabs = (typeof target === 'string' ? document.querySelector(target) : target),
        _eventTabsShow,
        _showTab = function (tabsLinkTarget) {
          var tabsPaneTarget, tabsLinkActive, tabsPaneShow;
          tabsPaneTarget = document.querySelector(tabsLinkTarget.getAttribute('href'));
          tabsLinkActive = tabsLinkTarget.parentElement.querySelector('.tabs__link_active');
          tabsPaneShow = tabsPaneTarget.parentElement.querySelector('.tabs__pane_show');
          // если следующая вкладка равна активной, то завершаем работу
          if (tabsLinkTarget === tabsLinkActive) {
            return;
          }
          // удаляем классы у текущих активных элементов
          if (tabsLinkActive !== null) {
            tabsLinkActive.classList.remove('tabs__link_active');
          }
          if (tabsPaneShow !== null) {
            tabsPaneShow.classList.remove('tabs__pane_show');
          }
          // добавляем классы к элементам (в завимости от выбранной вкладки)
          tabsLinkTarget.classList.add('tabs__link_active');
          tabsPaneTarget.classList.add('tabs__pane_show');
          document.dispatchEvent(_eventTabsShow);
        },
        _switchTabTo = function (tabsLinkIndex) {
          var tabsLinks = _elemTabs.querySelectorAll('.tabs__link');
          if (tabsLinks.length > 0) {
            if (tabsLinkIndex > tabsLinks.length) {
              tabsLinkIndex = tabsLinks.length;
            } else if (tabsLinkIndex < 1) {
              tabsLinkIndex = 1;
            }
            _showTab(tabsLinks[tabsLinkIndex - 1]);
          }
        };

      _eventTabsShow = new CustomEvent('tab.show', { detail: _elemTabs });

      _elemTabs.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var tabsLinkTarget = e.target;
        // завершаем выполнение функции, если кликнули не по ссылке
        if (!tabsLinkTarget.classList.contains('tabs__link')) {
          return;
        }
        // отменяем стандартное действие
        e.preventDefault();
        _showTab(tabsLinkTarget);
      });

      return {
        showTab: function (target) {
          _showTab(target);
        },
        switchTabTo: function (index) {
          _switchTabTo(index);
        }
      }

    };

    $tabs('.tabs');
```

Comment: Замените на `if (!tabsLinkTarget.closest('.tabs__link')) return`;

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение:

```
var $tabs = function (target) {
      var
        _elemTabs = (typeof target === 'string' ? document.querySelector(target) : target),
        _eventTabsShow,
        _showTab = function (tabsLinkTarget) {
          var tabsPaneTarget, tabsLinkActive, tabsPaneShow;
          tabsPaneTarget = document.querySelector(tabsLinkTarget.getAttribute('href'));
          tabsLinkActive = tabsLinkTarget.parentElement.querySelector('.tabs__link_active');
          tabsPaneShow = tabsPaneTarget.parentElement.querySelector('.tabs__pane_show');
          // если следующая вкладка равна активной, то завершаем работу
          if (tabsLinkTarget === tabsLinkActive) {
            return;
          }
          // удаляем классы у текущих активных элементов
          if (tabsLinkActive !== null) {
            tabsLinkActive.classList.remove('tabs__link_active');
          }
          if (tabsPaneShow !== null) {
            tabsPaneShow.classList.remove('tabs__pane_show');
          }
          // добавляем классы к элементам (в завимости от выбранной вкладки)
          tabsLinkTarget.classList.add('tabs__link_active');
          tabsPaneTarget.classList.add('tabs__pane_show');
          document.dispatchEvent(_eventTabsShow);
        },
        _switchTabTo = function (tabsLinkIndex) {
          var tabsLinks = _elemTabs.querySelectorAll('.tabs__link');
          if (tabsLinks.length > 0) {
            if (tabsLinkIndex > tabsLinks.length) {
              tabsLinkIndex = tabsLinks.length;
            } else if (tabsLinkIndex < 1) {
              tabsLinkIndex = 1;
            }
            _showTab(tabsLinks[tabsLinkIndex - 1]);
          }
        };

      _eventTabsShow = new CustomEvent('tab.show', { detail: _elemTabs });

      _elemTabs.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var target = e.target.closest('.tabs__link');
        // завершаем выполнение функции, если кликнули не по ссылке
        if (!target) {
          return;
        }
        // отменяем стандартное действие
        e.preventDefault();
        _showTab(target);
      });

      return {
        showTab: function (target) {
          _showTab(target);
        },
        switchTabTo: function (index) {
          _switchTabTo(index);
        }
      }

    };

    $tabs('.tabs');
```